# Add classes to jQuery datepicker

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I have a webpage with css that alter the default TABLE layout.

```
TABLE:not(.base) {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-style: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

TABLE:not(.base) > * > TR > * {
    border: 0.2rem solid #88F;
    padding: 0 0.375rem 0 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}

...
```

I want to use the JQuery datepicker, but it builds markup with tables, ending up with something ugly.
I'd like to add ".base" to all those tables but I can't find a way to do it properly.

Here's what I tried so far.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var formatCal = function (elt) {
        alert(elt);
        elt.find('TABLE').addClass('base');
    }

    $('#divCal').datepicker({
        beforeShow: formatCal
        , onSelect: function (val) {
            alert(val);
        }
    });

    formatCal($('#divCal'));
});
```

But everytime I select a date, the datepicker gets redrawn (without .base class).

What to do?

Comment: just add a class to parent div and target table using css http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/ggwGs/70/

Comment: I don't want to change how my current CSS is designed, I want to have jQuery UI make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be using MutationObserver.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var formatCal = function (elt) {
        elt.find('TABLE').addClass('base');
    }

    $('#divCal').datepicker({
        beforeShow: formatCal
        , onSelect: function (val) {
            alert(val);
        }
    });

    formatCal($('#divCal'));

    var observer = new MutationObserver(function (records) {
        var record = records[0];

        formatCal($(record.target));
    });

    // Configuration of the observer:
    var config = {
        attributes: false,
        childList: true,
        characterData: false
    };

    // Pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
    observer.observe($('#divCal > *').get(0), config);
});
```